# What's the benefits to use an abstract factory when using interfaces is already suffice?

Tags: design-patterns, factory, abstract-factory

I get the idea of the factory pattern, but I feel that it is really not necessary to use this pattern.

For example, below is some code I saw (C#) that use factory method:

```cs
public interface IAnimal
{
   void Speak();
}

public class Dog : IAnimal
{
   public void Speak()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Dog says: Bow-Wow.");
   }
}

public class Tiger : IAnimal
{
   public void Speak()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Tiger says: Halum.");
   }
}

public abstract class IAnimalFactory
{
   public abstract IAnimal CreateAnimal();
}

public class TigerFactory : IAnimalFactory
{
   public override IAnimal CreateAnimal()
   {
      return new Tiger();
   }
}

public class DogFactory : IAnimalFactory
{
   public override IAnimal CreateAnimal()
   {
      return new Dog();
   }
}
```

and client can invoke:

```cs
IAnimalFactory tigerFactory = new TigerFactory();
IAnimal aTiger = tigerFactory.MakeAnimal();
aTiger.Speak();  //3 lines of code, plus needing of extra factory classes
```

but Client can also do like:

```cs
IAnimal aTiger = new Tiger();
aTiger.Speak();  //only 2 lines of code
```

we can see that only 2 lines of code is needed, and we don't need to define factory classes.
so why takes extra steps to define and use factories?

Ant P replied that RandomNumberOfAnimalsGenerator needs a factory, but below is my version of the class, still doesn't need any factory.

```cs
public class RandomNumberOfAnimalsGenerator
{
    private readonly animal ;

    public RandomNumberOfAnimalsGenerator(IAnimal animal)
    {
        this.animal = animal;
    }

    public List<IAnimal> GetAnimals()
    {
        var animals = new List<IAnimal>();
        var n = RandomNumber();

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            animals.Add(animal);
        }

        return animals;
    }
}
```

and client invokes:

```cs
var RandomNumberOfAnimalsGenerator = new RandomNumberOfAnimalsGenerator(new Tiger());
```

still doesn't need a factory

Comment: A factory object can be passed as a parameter, making code that uses it create different classes for different callers.

Comment: @AntP  yes of course I know that. Your example is a little bit weird to me since you add SAME type of animal(I know they are DIFFERENT instances). From David Arno's answer, now I see why we need factory, thank you anyway

Comment: As noted in pschill's answer, you are describing the [abstract factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) not the [factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Comment: Your `RandomNumberOfAnimalsGenerator` *doesn't* make a random number of animals. It makes exactly 0 new animals, but it adds the same animal to the list several times. Animal factory version: pass it "dog", get [Fido, Spot, Max]. Your version: pass it "Fido", get [Fido, Fido, Fido].

Comment: `IAnimalFactory tigerFactory = new TigerFactory();` And then someday TigerFactory gets switched out for DogFactory, but the variable names will be left as is because scope propagation and too much effort and than new people will be brought into the project and the chaos will be glorious. :3

Comment: Why are you even using interfaces?? `IAnimal aTiger = new Tiger();` SMELLS. BAD. It is a tiger. You know it is a tiger. Just call it a tiger. The code is not generic. You only need interfaces when there actually can be instances of different objects (in some cases it only differs between tests and application, which is enough of a reason). Which means you use interfaces to handle objects passed from some other part of the code. Now when you do have use for interfaces, constructors can't be hidden behind them, because they construct specific class. That's where factories come in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure yet another answer is needed here, but you asked for your code to be modified to explain the purpose of factories. So perhaps the following will help.

Firstly, I'm going to change your `IAnimalFactory` to be an interface, rather than an abstract class. It serves no useful purpose being the latter. Also, we likely will have some criteria around what sort of animal we want for a specific circumstance. So let's have an `enum` that defines that criteria:

```cs
public enum AnimalType
{
    Pet,
    Wild
}
```

Then we can create our factory interface:

```cs
public interface IAnimalFactory
{
    IAnimal CreateAnimal(AnimalType typeofAnimal);
}
```

So now we have a means of letting other parts of the code create an animal, without having to know anything about what animals exist. We simply get to specify whether we want a wild one or not:

```cs
public void CreateAWildAnimalAndMakeItTalk(IAnimalFactory factory)
{
    var animal = factory.CreateAnimal(AnimalType.Wild);
    animal.Speak();
}
```

The only thing left to do is create an actual factory. Let's keep that simple:

```cs
internal class SimpleAnimalFactory : IAnimalFactory 
{
    public IAnimal CreateAnimal(AnimalType typeofAnimal)
    {
       return typeofAnimal == AnimalType.Wild ? new Tiger() : new Dog();
    }
}
```

And then it gets used elsewhere in the code:

```cs
CreateAWildAnimalAndMakeItTalk(new SimpleAnimalFactory());
```

But dogs can be wild too, so we might want to offer a different implementation of the factory:

```cs
internal class RandomWildAnimalFactory : IAnimalFactory 
{
    private Random _random = new Random();

    public IAnimal CreateAnimal(AnimalType typeofAnimal)
    {
        if (typeofAnimal == AnimalType.Pet) return new Dog();

        return _random.Next(2) == 0 ? new Tiger() : new Dog();
    }
}
```

Then we can call our method with the new factory, without having to change any other code:

```cs
CreateAWildAnimalAndMakeItTalk(new RandomWildAnimalFactory());
```

Comment: thank you very much. This example solve my problem!

Comment: to put it in one sentence, a factory move if else statement from client side to concrete factory.

Comment: @secondimage That's not at all what it does. It moves the responsibility of what is created away from the thing that needs it to be created. What that means in practice is totally dependent on the scenario. I need a factory when I want to control how and when an object is created but I want something else to dictate *what* is created.

Comment: Imagine a game, where you have enemies appearing in a particular pattern. You want to be able to create a bunch of any enemies, all of the same type, in any pattern. So you have a `EnemiesAtRegularIntervals`, `EnemiesAtRandomIntervals`, `EnemiesOnceAfterDelay` classes and each of them takes an `EnemyFactory` (or a `Func<IEnemy>`). Now the consumer gets to decide what enemies are created, but the pattern decides when. There's no implication of an "if else" statement here - the factory could just be as simple as `return new TankEnemy();`.

Answer (score 7):

*Factory methods* have a number of advantages. Mainly, they avoid the inbuilt limitations of constructors (can only have one name, cannot use caching, etc.).

Entire *Factories* are used mainly to decouple the client code from the concrete types used to instantiate the interface. But your example doesn't do this. Your client doesn't have to know the `Tiger` type, but instead it has to know the `TigerFactory` type, which is no improvement.

In my view, this is cargo cult programming - someone was told to use a factory and obeyed without understanding what the point of factories is. The proper thing to do would have been to have an `AnimalFactory` that can instantiate both tigers and dogs - but only if it can determine which to provide when. Otherwise, the decision about the concrete type of animal to use must stay with the client.

Comment: sorry I still don't get it. Could you modify my code to make it necessary to use Factory?

Comment: @secondimage There isn't a **short** piece of code that needs to use factory. It does become useful when the decision of *what* to make occurs thousands of lines (and billions of nanoseconds) before anything actually gets made.

Comment: @Caleth  can you use the concept of IAnimal to show me the easiest example that I need to use a factory, I will to find a counter example just like I did on `RandomNumberOfAnimalsGenerator`

Comment: @secondimage It isn't a case of "need/not need", its a "this is preferable to the alternative". That really only comes around in large systems. The simplest thing I can think of to describe an example is rendering options in PC games. Based on the chosen settings, you could have e.g. different `IModelFactory`, `ITextureFactory`, `IAntiAliasingFactory` handed off to the rendering component. But that doesn't *need* to be Factories

Answer (score 5):

There are different types of factories that serve different use cases. Often, you want to create objects of different (sub-) classes depending on runtime arguments. For this case, a simple function or a non-polymorphic class can be sufficient:

```
public class AnimalFactory
{
    public static IAnimal Create(String typeName)
    {
        if (typeName == "Tiger")
        {
            return new Tiger();
        }
        if (typeName == "Dog")
        {
            return new Dog();
        }
        // handle error, for example:
        throw Exception("Unkown type name: " + typeName);
    }
}
```

This factory allows you, for example, to create different animals depending on user input:

```
String userInput = Console.ReadLine();
IAnimal animal = AnimalFactory.Create(userInput);
animal.Speak();
```

As you already noticed, there is no need for a base class / interface `IAnimalFactory` with different factory subclasses. Here, those would only complicate the factory usage.

With above factory, whenever calling `Create`, you must provide the argument `userInput` that allows the type selection. However, in some cases, you want to separate the type selection from the actual creation. Take a look at the following example:

```
public class AnimalStore
{
    IAnimalFactory m_animalFactory;
    double m_price;
    public AnimalStore(IAnimalFactory animalFactory, double price)
    {
        this.m_animalFactory = animalFactory;
        this.m_price = price;
    }
    public void SellAnimalToUser(User user)
    {
        if (user.money < this.m_price)
        {
            throw Exception("Not enough money");
        }
        user.money -= this.m_price;
        user.AddAnimal(m_animalFactory.CreateAnimal());
    }
}
```

The `AnimalStore` is not polymorphic. However, different stores can still create different animals. When calling `SellAnimalToUser` (which calls `Create`), you dont need any argument that selects the correct animal type.

```
AnimalStore tigerStore = new AnimalStore(new TigerFactory(), 1000.);
AnimalStore dogStore = new AnimalStore(new DogFactory(), 200.);
User peter = new User();
peter.money = 5000;
tigerStore.SellAnimalToUser(peter);
dogStore.SellAnimalToUser(peter);
```

The problem of separating type selection from object creation can also be solved by other means. For example, you could have a non-polymorphic `AnimalFactory` that lets you specify the `String typeName` in its constructor instead of its `Create` function. Or you could inject functors instead of factories. These methods have their own advantages and disadvantages and which you want to use usually depends on how you want to use it.

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted.  The question is clearly about the abstract factory pattern, not factory methods as it claims.  The abstract factory pattern is largely overused when DI would be a better fit.  Factory methods have few downsides.

Comment: @JimmyJames, it’s because life’s too short to worry about real or imagined differences between near-identical patterns. They are all factories. So an answer that starts with a pedantic criticism of the specific type of factory being discussed needs a downvote. It’s not important.

Comment: @DavidArno They are not near identical.  That's blatantly false.  Specifically the part the OP is complaining about is not part of the factory method pattern.

Comment: @DavidArno Those two patterns serve two completely different use cases. That's like saying mixins and inheritance are the same thing. Sure they're superficially similar, but serve very different purposes.

Comment: @Voo, the use case is "I want to decouple the creation action from the thing that wants something created". That is a factory. Sure the GoF book chooses to detail two implementations of that pattern and then muddies the water by calling those two implementations separate *design* patterns, but that's just implementation details. Whether I inject an implementation of an interface, inject a function directly or provide it via inheritance/late binding, it's all just a factory. Anything else is pointless pedanticism  or implementation details.

Comment: @David If you pass an factory method via an interface or wrapper to a method you simply created abstract factory pattern where your interface is whatever static type you use for your wrapper (say Func<> in C#). At which point yes there's no real semantic difference between two implementations of the same pattern. But if you use the factory method as intended by the pattern those two simply have different use cases (e.g. compare Python's use of making sure there's only a single instance of integers to say a HttpClientFactory).

Comment: @JimmyJames, "*he abstract factory pattern is largely overused when DI would be a better fit*". As this answer's code example shows, injecting a factory (ie DI) works really well. DI and factories are orthogonal unless one uses a static factory, which would be an anti-pattern, and thus clearly using DI to inject the factory would be better.

Comment: @DavidArno "DI and factories are orthogonal unless one uses a static factory" You still haven't understood the difference between the two patterns, apparently.  Saying they are the same thing is like saying rooms and buildings are the same thing.  The abstract factory pattern is built on top of the factory method pattern.  This is explained right in the first paragraph of the wikipedia article.

Comment: @DavidArno "a static factory, which would be an anti-pattern"  That's an interesting viewpoint which goes against that of one of the [most influential software designers](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151)  in recent history.  On balance, I would say I find him more credible.

Comment: @DavidArno Here's an article about how [DI can replace abstract factories](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/dependency-injection/dependency-injection-replacing-factory-patterns.html).

Comment: @JimmyJames, nice article that walks through why DI is so much better than all those nasty "ask, don't tell" anti-patterns like static factories and locators. It misses two things though: 1. a DI container is a factory, so the factory still exists unless pure DI is used and 2. we still have the need for lazy creation scenarios that therefore need some form of factory to be injected. But despite those minor gripes, it's still a good article. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @DavidArno My main gripe with the article is that it presumes DI means a DI framework/tooling. That aside, the upshot is that prior to DI becoming mainstream, these abstract factory patterns (I include service locators in that set) were a popular approach. I was recently searching through some code that had factories that return factories of factories trying to find the code that actually does something; the approach is truly obnoxious.  But the factory method pattern is straightforward can be really useful, especially for creating immutable objects.

Answer (score 4):

The benefit of the Factory Method pattern is in expressing the fact that a piece of code does not want/need to know how to obtain an `IAnimal`.

In fact, interfaces are often viewed from the wrong perspective: you can never force client code to use your interface.

Rather, the client code can *specify* that it requires an interface, in this case, "a way to create animals".

It would not be so dumb that the client code even *defined* the interface itself, expressing that: "you take care of creation, I'll put them in a zoo".

Note that this pattern was defined in an era where programming languages had no lambda expressions.  In today's context, many of the patterns have become obsolete.  The Factory Method can now be implemented with a simple `Func<IAnimal>`:

```
public void myCode(Func<IAnimal> createAnimal) {
   var a = createAnimal();
   ... // stuff with a
}
```

Comment: "*Note that this pattern was defined in an era where programming languages had no lambda expressions*". I'm not sure this is true as the GoF patterns were invented for C++ (I think) and C supported function points for many years prior to its publication. But I completely agree with you that abstract factory implementations using interfaces and classes are over-engineered compared with a simple `Func<T>` solution.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for an example of why you'd ever need a factory but you haven't really been given one yet.

Suppose you have a piece of code that creates a random number of animals. How do you decouple this from the details of how to create a specific type of animal?

The answer: a factory.

```
public class RandomNumberOfAnimalsGenerator
{
    private readonly Func<IAnimal> createAnimal;

    public RandomNumberOfAnimalsGenerator(Func<IAnimal> createAnimal)
    {
        this.createAnimal = createAnimal;
    }

    public List<IAnimal> GetAnimals()
    {
        var animals = new List<IAnimal>();
        var n = RandomNumber();

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            animals.Add(createAnimal());
        }

        return animals;
    }
}
```

Without this *factory*, `RandomNumberOfAnimalsGenerator` needs to know how to create every type of animal.

Comment: This is still fairly contrived, and could instead be `public class RandomNumberOfAnimalsGenerator<T> where T : IAnimal { ... }`

Comment: @Ant P I have updated my post to create a `RandomNumberOfAnimalsGenerator` without using a factory, could you have a look?

Comment: @secondimage That creates a list of a random number of references to *the same animal*

Comment: @Caleth yes it will create only the same type of animal, but how you can create different type of animals? can you show me the client code that how to invoke `RandomNumberOfAnimalsGenerator`? I don't think a func delegate can allow to do that

Comment: @secondimage `var randomNumberOfRandomAnimalsGenerator = new RandomNumberOfAnimalsGenerator(() => RandomBoolean() ? new Tiger() : new Dog())`

Comment: @secondimage contrast `var randomNumberOfTigersGenerator = new RandomNumberOfAnimalsGenerator(() => new Tiger());`

Comment: @Caleth  but there is still no fundamental difference, and what is the factory in this case? still no factory involved

Comment: @AntP do you mean the only benefit of using factory is to let factory invoke constructor internally, so client doesn't need to use `new XXX()`?

Comment: @secondimage `() => RandomBoolean() ? new Tiger() : new Dog()` is the factory. `Func<IAnimal>` is the abstract factory type.

Answer (score 0):

One use I haven't seen in these answers that's really common but you are kind of looking at the problem backwards (Your example code is both consuming and creating the factory, which isn't generally useful).  A good use for it is where there are 2+ sets of code interacting (maintained by completely different teams).

Let's take something like a log library as an example... This might be a utility class that you use to log out to a file.

Suppose the log has quite a few destinations, File, database, console, … that you can configure through either configuration commands or a config file, but what if you want to log to some other device--a remote port, or some strange old paper tape punch you found in your closet?  On top of that you want any other libraries that you are using that might use the same logging software to use YOUR special logging back-end.

In other words, how can you supply the logger with code it should run when it logs?

I can see 3 ways:

1. add your class name to the logging library's config file
2. Provide the logger with a concrete instance of your logging back-end
3. provide a factory to the logging library that it can use to create it's own instances of your logging back-end.

2 and 3 are close--the main difference is that if the library needs a new logging backend each time the client code creates a logger, then solution 2 wouldn't work and you'd need a factory.

Looking at it from the user's point of view you hardly even see that it uses an abstract factory, but when you look at it as an implementer of the logging library, it seems quite necessary.

Answer (score -2):

Your code is not an example of factory method. Factory method is just one single method, it is usually a static (in case of java). Having abstract method which is overloaded in different derivations doesn't make sense because in that case you need to create real single factory method to instantiate entities of implementation.

I suppose your code is part of Factory pattern (not FactoryMethod) which is different. Factory includes factory method as a starting point to create itself. Moreover IFactory can (and should to be useful) contain multiple methods for each interface in a set of types involved in process of multiple implementation.
For example.

```
public abstract class IAnimalFactory {
    public abstract IAnimal CreateAnimal();
    public abstract ILocation CreateLocation();
    public abstract IFood CreateFood();
}

class Zoo extends ILocation;
class Savannah extends ILocation;

IAnimal.placeTo(ILocation);
```

And so on.

Answer (score -2):

Your `RandomNumberOfAnimalsGenerator` doesn't make a random number of animals. It makes precisely zero animals, in fact. What it does do is create a new list, containing several references to the same animal.

For a `RandomNumberOfAnimalsGenerator`, I should be able to pass it "dog" and get back a list: Fido, Spot, Max.

If I then feed the dogs: `foreach(IAnimal a in randomlyGeneratedAnimals) {a.Feed();}` then I feed three dogs once.

With *your* `RandomNumberOfAnimalsGenerator`, I can pass it "Fido" and get back a list: Fido, Fido, Fido.

If I then feed the dogs: `foreach(IAnimal a in randomlyGeneratedAnimals) {a.Feed();}` then I feed Fido three times.

In your program, I can't tell the difference, because all dogs are identical, because they don't have any fields. If I add a field:

```
public interface IAnimal
{
   void Speak();
   void Feed();
}

public class Dog : IAnimal
{
   public void Speak()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Dog says: Bow-Wow.");
   }
   private int Hunger = 5;
   public void Feed()
   {
      Hunger--;
      Console.WriteLine("Hunger level is "+Hunger);
   }
}
```

then you will get different results, if you have the same dog three times instead of having three different dogs.